# Xcode error: no copy of vecLib.framework found locally

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am getting this error when I try and run an iOS app via device (not simulator) from Xcode.

```
  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation (file not found).
warning: No copy of MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom (file not found).
warning: No copy of Bom.framework/Bom found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libbz2.1.0.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings (file not found).
warning: No copy of AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices (file not found).
warning: No copy of FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libAccessibility.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore (file not found).
warning: No copy of JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices (file not found).
warning: No copy of StoreServices.framework/StoreServices found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore (file not found).
warning: No copy of IMCore.framework/IMCore found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco (file not found).
warning: No copy of Marco.framework/Marco found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices (file not found).
warning: No copy of FTServices.framework/FTServices found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration (file not found).
warning: No copy of ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation (file not found).
warning: No copy of IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/usr/lib/libmis.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libmis.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Librarian.framework/Librarian (file not found).
warning: No copy of Librarian.framework/Librarian found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection (file not found).
warning: No copy of PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration (file not found).
warning: No copy of DataMigration.framework/DataMigration found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService (file not found).
warning: No copy of ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi (file not found).
warning: No copy of MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork (file not found).
warning: No copy of CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X (file not found).
warning: No copy of EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libtidy.A.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreImage.framework/CoreImage found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices (file not found).
warning: No copy of DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreText.framework/CoreText found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit (file not found).
warning: No copy of WebKit.framework/WebKit found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore (file not found).
warning: No copy of WebCore.framework/WebCore found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader (file not found).
warning: No copy of ProofReader.framework/ProofReader found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit (file not found).
warning: No copy of PrintKit.framework/PrintKit found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL (file not found).
warning: No copy of OpenCL.framework/OpenCL found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES (file not found).
warning: No copy of OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox (file not found).
warning: No copy of VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight (file not found).
warning: No copy of FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer (file not found).
warning: No copy of IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (file not found).
warning: No copy of AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime (file not found).
warning: No copy of CoreTime.framework/CoreTime found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libxslt.1.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libiconv.2.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5288d)/Symbols/usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libresolv.9.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using an device that runs iOS 5.0 but your Xcode is still using 4.3?